# SQL Max Date of multiple columns, return column name

Tags: sql-server-2008, max

Using MS SQL Server 2008, I'm doing a query to calculate the Max date of 10 Columns for each Row.  That query is below.  I also need to list the name of that column that has the Max date.  So the Query would give me the [Last Step Date] and the [Last Step Name].  How do I get the [Last Step Name]?

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate)
        FROM   (VALUES ([Step 1]),
                       ([Step 2]),
                       ([Step 3]),
                       ([Step 4]),
                       ([Step 5]),
                       ([Step 6]),
                       ([Step 7]),
                       ([Step 8]),
                       ([Step 9]),
                       ([Step 10]) ) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate)) AS [Last Step Date]
FROM   MyTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT ca.ColName, ca.LastUpdateDate
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM (VALUES
                       ('Step1', [Step 1]),
                       ('Step2', [Step 2]),
                       ('Step3', [Step 3]),
                       ('Step4', [Step 4]),
                       ('Step5', [Step 5]),
                       ('Step6', [Step 6]),
                       ('Step7', [Step 7]),
                       ('Step8', [Step 8]),
                       ('Step9', [Step 9]),
                       ('Step10', [Step 10]) ) UpdateDate(ColName, LastUpdateDate)
                    ORDER  BY LastUpdateDate DESC)ca
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0820f/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works!  I still need to work something out as when I inserted it into the entire query that is multiple temp tables coming together, it's pulling the same value for all rows, but I should be able to figure that out.